# ffmpeg - extract frames from video from multiple files to add to Keyboard Maestro macro

Tags: ffmpeg, automation, time-lapse

First I would like to say that I use MacOS, I am new using ffmpeg and keyboard maestro and have no little to none experience in coding. But I think I did learned a bit is the past few weeks trying to solve the problem I will ask now. Believe me I tried searching for answers online and did a lot of trial and error before coming here to ask my question. so here is what I am trying to do:

I have a folder (/Users/Documents/clips) with 450 short AVI clips (foto1.avi, foto2.avi...., foto450.avi) from which I would like to extract all frames from. I know how to extract all frames from 1 clip and copy them to an existing directory:

*ffmpeg -i /Users/Documents/clips/foto1.avi /Users/Documents/Frames/Foto1/frame%06d.png *

With their command all frames from the clip Foto1.avi (frame000001.png, frame000002.png...., frame000132.png) are copied to the folder /Foto1.

With keyboard Maestro I created 450 folders named afters the 450 .avi clips.

Is there a way to write a ffmpeg command that will extract the frames of all 450 .avi clips to the folder with the same name as the file?

I was hoping there would be a way of seeing variables in this kind of way:

ffmpeg -i /Users/Documents/clips/foto%.avi /Users/Documents/Frames/Foto%/frame%06d.png

I really appreciate any help. Thank you!

I tried searching for answers in forums, ffmpeg database. And since I have almost no knowledge on coding sometimes is hard to decipher and understand the meaning of the code.